# Audio mixer to feed app output back into a mic - ideally mix it with an existing mic

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, mixer

Pretty much what it says on the tin. Backstory: On Windows 11 I'd like to inject some lofi music into our Teams/Zoom calls without taking over screen share. Ideally, I'd like to mix the firefox output with my mic input for a combined stream, so music "comes from" my mic and someone else can screen share. I'd need the ability to independently control levels of each. I thought I used to have an app for this but Google has been withholding its secrets.

Comment: I never played around with the audio part, but OBS and teams works great.  (I use it to mix  in my main desktop as 'webcam' with myself in a corner and a clock in the other corner.) Worth checking out since I am reasonably confident it does this.

Comment: oh wow I didn't even consider OBS type setups. I don't use video on my calls so just didn't think of it